# SpringSecurity: how to specify remember me authentication?

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I'm developing an app based on Grails and Vaadin 7. I managed to make them work with SpringSecurity for authentication and authorization, but I had to develop my own Service that calls the Spring Security authentication manager to make it work with Vaadin:

```
class SecurityService {

    static transactional = true

    def springSecurityService
    def authenticationManager

    void signIn(String username, String password) {
        try {
            def authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            SCH.context.authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication)
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Invalid username/password")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that now I need to implement a `remember me` authentication and I don't know from where to start.

How do I make the `authenticationManager` know that I want it to use `remeberMeAuthentication`? I can get a boolean value from a checkbox on the login View, but what do I do with it next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is specific to the handling of checkbox value (remember me flag) coming from login page, the answer is that you have to call `loginSuccess` or `loginFail` method of [RememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/RememberMeServices.html). The `loginSuccess` adds auto-login cookie in the response and `loginFail` removes that cookie.

But I guess above answer won't help you much unless you are sure that you have `RememberMeServices` configured in your app. Maybe following steps that configure `RememberMeServices` will help you do whole thing your way (or help you understand the out of the box functionality):

(1) Create a class (call it myRememberMeServices) that implements `RememberMeServices` and [LogoutHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html).

(2) In `autoLogin` method, create an authentication object (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) after parsing the cookie value.

(3) In `loginFail` method, cancel the cookie.

(4) In `loginSuccess` method, create an auto-login cookie. Add value that you would use in autoLogin method. Usually cookie value is encrypted.

(5) In `logout` method , cancel the cookie.

(6) Inject myRememberMeServices in following four places and call appropriate method:

```
(a) At the time of successful login (if checkbox value is set),     
(b) At the time of failed login,   
(c) On logout, and   
(d) In filter that does autologin
```

It is worth noting that [RememberMeAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.html) takes `authenticationManager` and `RememberMeServices` in its constructor.

Answer to your other question is that the `authenticationManager` doesn't need to know anything about remember me. It is the filter (or any class handling auto login) that needs to know about `authenticationManager` and `RememberMeServices`. (In other words, ask `RememberMeServices` for a token and pass it to `authenticationManager` to do auto login).

Comment: Thank you for your guidelines. I'll try to go deeper into SpringSecurity and Vaadin. I can't check if your answer is full right now, but I guess it gives an outline of what should be done, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security's architecture is based on servlet filters. The sign-in mechanism you have implemented above is normally done by the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. Another filter called `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` takes the responsibility for the remember-me functionality. The `authenticationManager` is not aware at all whether the remember-me feature is used by the application or not.

If you want to integrate Spring Security with another web-framework, first try to find out how the filters of the two frameworks can play together.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by my answer, it might be easier to do than it first seems. You just need a good understanding of the architecture of the frameworks you work with. To get an overview of the fundamental architecture of Spring Security, I would recommend reading the 6th, 8th and 9th chapter of the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/springsecurity.html). It's altogether around 20 printed pages, not so horrible.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to go deeper into SpringSecurity and Vaadin.